# How do I upload to AWS S3 from iOS without Cognito?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**My Goal:**

Upload photos from iOS to a common AWS S3 bucket with the simplest code possible

---

**What I've Tried:**

- Reading the [aws-sdk-ios repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios)
- Reading the [S3 Upload Files page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html)
- Reading the [Cognito FAQ page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html)
- Reading [various](http://shrikar.com/ios-app-development-upload-images-to-aws-s3/) [blogs](http://sledgedev.com/aws-s3-image-upload-using-aws-sdk-for-ios-v2/) and SO questions
- Creating a Cognito pool with a client app

---

**Assumptions of Best Practices:**

I assume that Cognito is the default way to set up image uploading after all of the reading I've done. However, I have two problems with doing it this way:

1. It seems overly complicated for something where I should just need to pass the image, bucket, key, and secret.
2. I have already done this through a server before with just key and secret, so I don't see a reason to use or pay for Cognito.

---

**My Questions:**

- Is there a way to upload from iOS to AWS S3 without using Cognito?
- If any of my above assumptions or questions are not the best way to realize my goal, then what is the simplest way to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cognito Identity is a free service so you don't really have to pay for it. Also you really shouldn't be using hardcoded credentials in your app since it can be easily decompiled and retrieved which is not the scenario in case of a server side code.

For iOS SDK you can use `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider` as a way to provide the static credentials to any service client.

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:@"YourAccessKey" secretKey:@"YourSecretKey"];
```

Again you really shouldn't be doing this in a production app.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's good to know how to do it statically, but I'll take your advice and use server or cognito. Much appreciated!

Comment: Not a free service (maybe was at the time?)

Comment: Cognito Federated Identity is still a free service. Cognito user pools is not free

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that never use AWS in Moblie Application without Cognito.

If you still want to do that you can create an IAM user set policy to your bucket resources  and put the IAM user credential to your code

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new AWSCredentials() {     
        @Override
        public String getAWSSecretKey() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "YOUR_SECRETKEY";
        }
        
        @Override
        public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "YOUR_IAM_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID";
        }
    };

    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

Note that the method is dangerous to use!!
You can set AWS S3 Bucket permission policy instead: [S3 permission policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

Answer (score 0):

The part of cognito require to make this work is free. From the [cognito FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/faqs/):

"The Federated Identities feature for authenticating users and generating unique identifiers is always free with Cognito Identity."

Additionally, there is a method in the AWS SDK, [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) which will allow you to assume a role defined in AWS IAM using an openid connect provider. If you're not using an open id connect provider but you've managed to authenticate with your backend nonetheless, you can use [Cognito.GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) to provide you a token for this use case.

A great resource for understanding that is here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-2-developer-authenticated-identities/